# Why do some people cycle musical tastes, and some people continually listen to the same type of music?

Tags: music

This is solely based on a personal observation of mine, but I've noticed people like me who constantly cycle music taste, and others who always listen to the same type of music.

I, for example, change musical tastes every 2-3 months, because I get sick of the same thing, but will eventually come back to it within a couple of years.

But I notice people who only listen to EDM, or only listen to rap, or only listen to alternative, etc.

Has any studies been done on this subject?

I noticed some studies about music changing with age, but that isn't exactly the same thing.

Comment: While this is an interesting question, I suspect it is too broad. There would be many personality aspects dictating musical preferences.